# Marshalling error when using a C++ library from a C# application

Tags: c#, c++, interop, marshalling

I am trying to use a C++ DLL in C# and having some issues between the two with a specific function.

In C++ the function is defined as:

```
byte* GetEntityUserData(TEntity entity)
```

In C# I've defined it as:

```
[DllImport(EngineDll)]
public static extern object[] GetEntityUserData(TEntity entity);
```

When I try to do the following usage:

```
object[] o = LE.GetEntityUserData(entity);
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination.

The C# program compiles, but it gives the run-time error.

Comment: Change the C++ declaration to void*, that's a more accurate representation of "here's a blob of bytes, good luck sorting it out". IntPtr on the managed side, Marshal class to slap some sense into it.  Clearly it is not an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the data supposed to represent? I would change the C# signature to return `byte[]`, not `object[]`. You won't be able to get a reference type back from an unmanaged function. Only value types, which means primitive types and `struct`'s.

Comment: Yeah, knowing more about what the data is on the C++ side would help.  One problem with sending byte* back (which I assume is a char*?  What is "byte" defined as on the C++ side?) is that the CLR marshaler will not know how many bytes to marshal back, so you likely need to provide more information to the marshaler (via MarshalAsAttribute), but to give good guidance we'd need to know what the data really will be or how a caller knows how many bytes are in the byte*

Comment: So it's just an opaque blob that you want to get and later send back to native code?  You're not going to use it on the managed side?

Comment: @user441521: If you don't need to make use of it, you can type the return type as `IntPtr` and just hold onto it.

Comment: I tried going the IntPtr type but it wasn't letting me cast the class object to InPtr. Is there some special cast I need to do in order to do that?

The idea is basically having a model variable inside a class. The engine works only on the model type. So when callbacks from the engine are called the parameters to these callbacks are of these engine types. It knows nothing of the actual class I'm making for my game. Being able to store the class object inside the engine types (like a model) is how you can get back to the class object from the engine type when engine callbacks are called.

Comment: Hey Austin, I want to use it on the managed side again. When the engine fires callbacks it adds the model as a parameter. That's how I would get it back. You are basically storing a pointer to a class inside the model variable so that you can retrieve it back when a callback is called.

Comment: @user441521: If this is an actual *object* (a class in C++, not a `struct`) then you cannot do what you're trying to do. You'll have to write a C++/CLI project that provides a wrapper for your C++ dll.

Comment: What if in C# I make a struct that has a member variable that is of a class object? Then pass the struct to the SetEntityUserData method?

Comment: @user441521: Only `struct` and primitive member values can be passed to (or returned from) an unmanaged function. The marshaler does have logic for processing arrays of the same types, but that's the only exception. This restriction extends to nested objects as well. If you have to interact with a class defined in C++, then you have no choice but to use C++/CLI. Note that you can get a pointer to a class instance back (as `IntPtr`) and can pass that around as much as you like, but you can't actually dereference it into an instance of anything.